# Problem requesting from server localhost apache mysql

Tags: php, http, localhost

I'm having a problem when sending an HTTP POST request to my local server. These are the errors that I get:

```
POST http://XXX.X.X.X:3306/login.php net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error
```

I believe it has something to do with the URL. When I open up the login.php file on my local browser, it seems to be working with no problems so something makes me think that it could be the port that is incorrect for the URL.

This is my typescript code that sends the POST request:

```
private getloginURL = "http://XXX.X.X.X:3306/login.php";
// methods
  logIn(username: string, password: string) {
    let sendData = new FormData();
    sendData.append('username', username);
    sendData.append('password', password);


    this.http.post(this.getloginURL, sendData, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data=> {
        console.log(data);
        this.currLoginStatus.next(data); // pushing data into behavior subject
    });
```

How do I find the correct URL to my local server? I am using Apache and mySQL. Thanks!

EDIT:

For port 80, these are the errors I got:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1/login.php 404 (Not Found)

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1/login.php' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error
```

For port 443, I got the same errors as I did previously when I used port 3306.

Comment: 3306 is (most likely) your MySQL port, and not your web server port, which will (most likely) be 80 or 443. If by local server you mean, running on the same machine, then you can just use `http://localhost/login.php`. If you mean, a server running the same local LAN, then we can't possibly know that.

Comment: Also note that login credentials should be posted to https not http, otherwise they can be easily stolen.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks for your reply! Port 3306 was my MySQL port indeed, just as you stated. I made in edit in my post based off your suggestion. Please check that out and let me know what you think. Do you know what file would tell me what port number I need?